# Allow me to list education without a major/minor in my Careers profile

Tags: feature-request, jobs

It may be that I'm misinterpreting the intention behind the "Education" part of my Careers profile, but I'd like to be able to include education that I've received that didn't have a major or minor associated, since I'm currently a high school student and thus haven't been through higher education.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Education section is to list any educational qualifications you've earned. It doesn't need to be a degree, so you don't need to specify "major" or "minor" if that's not how what you're studying is structured. It's a free text field so you can type what you want.

If you've earned some kind of relevant high school qualification (say, a diploma or GCSE), you can list it here. If you're working towards one, just add "[in progress]" at the end.

Comment: I meant, " allow me to not fill out that field," but I see what you're saying. thanks.